# JQuery / JavaScript - Accessing methods

Tags: jquery

I'm sort of new to JavaScript programming and I do not understand method access. I have a bit of code that looks like the following:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myCustomUIElement = function (options) {
        var props = { value: 1  }; 

        return this.each(function () { initialize(); }); 
        function initialize() { /* initialization code */  }

        function toggle() { if (props.value == 1) { props.value = 0; } else { props.value = 1; } }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

My HTML Page has an anchor tag that is responsible for toggling the state of myCustomUIElement. The HTML that shows this and initializes myCustomUIElement is shown here:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>        
<a href="#" onclick="toggleFromHtml('myElement');">toggle</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myElement").myCustomUIElement();
    });

    function toggleFromHtml(e) {
        $("#" + e).toggle();
    }
</script>
```

My problem is, the toggle method in the myCustomUIElement object is never called. I can call the toggleFromHtml just fine. How do I access a method that is defined in JavaScript as shown above? Is there a way? Please note, I do not want to re-write the JavaScript shown in the first snippet if possible. If possible, I want to call the method from the toggleFromHtml method.

Thank you!

Comment: I'll keep looking at this, I think I initially misunderstood your question, but basically this is creating a jQuery plugin.

Comment: .toggle(); is a private method in your plugin code. You would need to do something like $.fn.toggle() = function(options) {/*dostuff*/} to access it in the way you are trying to. Also, I believe toggle is already a method in JQuery; you would probably want to name it something else. You could also access it as $.fn.mycustomUIElement.toggle = function(){} and $('selector').myCustomUIElement.toggle()

Comment: @mervyn the problem is, I can't access the props property from a new method named something like $.fn.myFunction = function(){}. That's where my problem stems from. But I'm not sure how to overcome it.

Comment: toggleFromHtml(e) is going to call the jQuery.toggle() method (See: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). You cannot call a method that is not exposed. I am unsure as to what you are trying to accomplish exactly and need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the start of a plugin there, you need to extend the jQuery object. Here is an example, notice `$.fn.extend({})` `myCustomUIElement()` will be your method name

the jQuery plugin

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
    myCustomUIElement: function(options){
        return this.each(function(){
            new $.MyCustomUIElement(this, options);
        });
    }
});

$.MyCustomUIElement = function(target, options){
    var $target = $(target);

    $target.bind('click', {}, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // your event code
        alert(options.myVar + ' ' + $(this).text());
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

your init javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrap .myElement').myCustomUIElement({
        myVar: 'click me!'
    });
});
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <a class="myElement" href="#">toggle 1</a>
    <a class="myElement" href="#">toggle 2</a>
</div>
```